# Fill between two circles in Tikz with addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, circles, axis

I want to draw the following graph with specific region filled

[image]

This is my code, I only get the result right of the x-axis. when I change `clip={domain=0:3}` to `clip={domain=-3:3}` it didn't work

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-5.5,xmax=5.5,ymin=-5.5,ymax=5.5,ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6},yticklabels={$-5$,$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$},   xtick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6},xticklabels={$-5$,$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$},width=\textwidth]   
    \addplot[domain=-3:3,samples=101,smooth,thick,name path=A]{sqrt(9-x^2)}  node {};
    \addplot[domain=-3:3,samples=101,smooth,thick,name path=B]{-sqrt(9-x^2)}  node {};
    \addplot[domain=-2:2,samples=101,smooth,thick,name path=C,color=white]{sqrt(4-x^2)}  node {};
    \addplot[domain=-2:2,samples=101,smooth,thick,name path=D,color=white]{-sqrt(4-x^2)}  node {};
    \addplot [gray!20] fill between [ of=C and A,soft clip={domain=0:3}];
    \addplot [gray!20] fill between [ of=D and B,soft clip={domain=0:3}];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier without `fillbetween` in this case. A simple `even odd rule` does it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-5.5,xmax=5.5,ymin=-5.5,ymax=5.5,
    ytick={-5,...,-1,1,2,...,6},
    yticklabels={$-5$,$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$},
    xtick={-5,...,-1,1,2,...,6},
    xticklabels={$-5$,$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$},   
    width=\textwidth,
    set layers]   
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
     \fill[gray!20,even odd rule] (0,0) circle[radius=3] circle[radius=2]; 
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % just to have some plot
    \addplot[domain=0:356.4,samples=101,smooth cycle]   ({3*cos(x)},{3*sin(x)});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a version with round circles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,axis on top,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-5.5,xmax=5.5,ymin=-5.5,ymax=5.5,
    ytick={-5,...,-1,1,2,...,6},
    yticklabels={$-5$,$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$},
    xtick={-5,...,-1,1,2,...,6},
    xticklabels={$-5$,$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$},   
    width=\textwidth,
    set layers,axis equal image]   
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
     \fill[gray!20,even odd rule] (0,0) circle[radius=3] circle[radius=2]; 
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % just to have some plot
    \addplot[domain=0:356.4,samples=101,smooth cycle]   ({3*cos(x)},{3*sin(x)});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The coordinate system tells me these are circles, but to my well-trained eyes they look an awful lot like ellipses! :D

Comment: @Circumscribe I added a nonrelativistic, round version. (One only has to add `axis equal` or `axis equal image`.)

Comment: Thanks, much better!
(I like my circles stationary.)